# glTexImage2D null data pointer and memory initialization

Tags: opengl

Let's assume that 2D texture is defined using `glTexImage2D` with the null data pointer. Does passing the null data pointer zeroes memory or I may get some garbage data when a fragment shader samples that texture ?

```
vec3 color = texture(texture0, texCoord).xyz;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation clearly states](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml):

> data may be a null pointer. In this case, texture memory is allocated to accommodate a texture of width width and height height. ... **The image is undefined** if the user tries to apply an uninitialized portion of the texture image to a primitive.

So yes -- you will get garbage. Keep in mind that zeroes are also valid garbage, so don't use that as a proof that it "works".

The easiest way to clear a texture to all-zeros is [with `glClearTexImage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearTexImage.xhtml):

```
glClearTexImage(texture, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

For this function `data == 0` actually means "all zeroes".